# Using CSV file vs. sqlite db in an iOS application

Tags: ios, sqlite, csv

I have a dataset that I need to store locally in an iOS application. There are about 3000 rows in the dataset. For each row, there will be a column that has a unique identifier(like a primary key). I am looking at two options here to host it in my web service:
Option 1 - host the CSV file
vs.
Option 2 - return all the data in a json array.

Option 1:
Download and store the CSV file from my web service, read the CSV file into memory(parse it into a NSDictionary for example, would take O(N) to do this), and it would take O(1) to find a key value pair.

Option 2:
I use sqlite in my app right now and I can save the dataset to a table. I am not sure what is the time complexity of saving to the table and also querying for a row in this case. Maybe it is O(n) saving to the table and O(log(n)) querying because there will be a primary key?

Option 1 vs Option 2 which one is faster and more reliable?

Comment: You could also store the SQLite database and have the app get it, removing the need for the app to parse data.  Though, for only 3000 rows, it seems like the best answer is probably whatever's easiest to maintain.

Comment: @AnonCoward, some of the data might change in the dataset and that is why I will host it in my web service.

Comment: That doesn't change anything I wrote.

Comment: @AnonCoward, I am sorry but I am confused, how can I avoid parsing the json here?

Comment: Whatever produces the CSV or JSON could produce a SQLite database and publish it to a website for the device app to download.

Comment: Server can create "Create" or "Insert" statement for your 3K records much faster than iOS. Get all in one request and execute those Query into your DB. It will save your parsing/fetching time.